# Pass data from the pipeline to views in Django Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-views, python-social-auth

I was reading the documentation of Python Social Auth and got curious about the section of [Interrupting the Pipeline (and communicating with views)](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-docs/blob/master/docs/developer_intro.rst#interrupting-the-pipeline-and-communicating-with-views).

In there, we see the following pipeline code

```
In our pipeline code, we would have:

from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from social_core.pipeline.partial import partial

# partial says "we may interrupt, but we will come back here again"
@partial
def collect_password(strategy, backend, request, details, *args, **kwargs):
    # session 'local_password' is set by the pipeline infrastructure
    # because it exists in FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION
    local_password = strategy.session_get('local_password', None)
    if not local_password:
        # if we return something besides a dict or None, then that is
        # returned to the user -- in this case we will redirect to a
        # view that can be used to get a password
        return redirect("myapp.views.collect_password")

    # grab the user object from the database (remember that they may
    # not be logged in yet) and set their password.  (Assumes that the
    # email address was captured in an earlier step.)
    user = User.objects.get(email=kwargs['email'])
    user.set_password(local_password)
    user.save()

    # continue the pipeline
    return
```

and the following view

```
def get_user_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # because of FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION, this will get copied
            # to the request dictionary when the pipeline is resumed
            request.session['local_password'] = form.cleaned_data['secret_word']

            # once we have the password stashed in the session, we can
            # tell the pipeline to resume by using the "complete" endpoint
            return redirect(reverse('social:complete', args=("backend_name,")))
    else:
        form = PasswordForm()

    return render(request, "password_form.html")
```

Specially interested in the line

```
return redirect(reverse('social:complete', args=("backend_name,")))
```

which is used to redirect the user back to the pipeline using an already stablished backend.

We can see [earlier in that page](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-docs/blob/master/docs/developer_intro.rst#understanding-the-pipeline) a condition that's used to check which backend is being used.

```
def my_custom_step(strategy, backend, request, details, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name != 'my_custom_backend':
        return
    # otherwise, do the special steps for your custom backend
```

The question is, instead of manually adding it in the `args=("backend_name,")`, how can the pipeline communicate the correct backend to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can simply add in the pipeline

```
request.session['backend'] = backend.name
```

and then the view becomes

```
backend_name = request.session['backend']
return redirect(reverse('social:complete', args=(backend_name)))
```